# GoogleMaps is not appearing - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to learn about using GoogleMaps API using the Maps Compose Library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose). It's "working" but the map isn't quite showing up correctly. What's happening?

[image: Screen]

```
@Composable
fun MyMap() {
    var uiSettings by remember { mutableStateOf(MapUiSettings()) }
    var properties by remember {
        mutableStateOf(MapProperties(mapType = MapType.SATELLITE))`
    }

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        GoogleMap(
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
            properties = properties,
            uiSettings = uiSettings
        )
        Switch(
            checked = uiSettings.zoomControlsEnabled,
            onCheckedChange = {
                uiSettings = uiSettings.copy(zoomControlsEnabled = it)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API key is wrong here

```kotlin
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY" />
```

Visit https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/google/maps-apis/credentials